# Child method to update parent state

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I know the standard is to the parent to pass down a method for which the child will call to update the state.

However my parent is getting too many methods.

Is there any way to have the children components updating the parent with their own methods, so the parent doesn't have like hundred functions?

e.g.:

```
parentState: {
    stateBlue: { ... },
    stateRed: { ... },
    stateGreen: { ... }
}

ParentComponent

    ChildComponentBlue
        method1
        method2
        method3

    ChildComponenRed
        method1
        method2
        method3

    ChildComponenGreen
        method1
        method2
        method3
```

Comment: Someone is probably going to tell you to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). And they'd be right.

Comment: @Jordan the app is using Redux, but this part is not, as it's something very local.

Comment: I think I didn't explain very well. Actually the child is not really a child. It's only a bunch of related methods. I'm not using redux here because they are all related to UI display. But the solution of static methods seems to be great.

Answer (score -1):

I am using static methods in my child components and it's working like a charm.